# search in php based on user id key in

Tags: php, mysql

I tried this code but it displays nothing. It should display a table when I key in the user id 
this is my full code (all in one page) . Can u check the code for me? How am I suppose to call other user id using the code below?

```
<head>
<title>action</title>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="#333333">
<form name="form1" action="test.php" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<p><img src="joho.jpg" width="334" height="203"> <img src="msc.jpg" width="769" height="200"> 
</p>
<p> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
  <?php
session_start();
?>
  <?php
include 'config1.php';

$userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
$query  = "SELECT * FROM login where userid='$userid'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<b>WELCOME {$row['userid']} AS {$row['userrole']} </b>";
} 
?>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<kbd>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
  <A HREF = logout.php><b><font size="5">LOG OUT</font></b></A> <b>&nbsp;</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</kbd></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><kbd>Search user based on user id :&nbsp;</kbd>&nbsp;&nbsp; </p>

        <input type="text" name="search" size = "30">
        <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="SEARCH" />
      </form>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;
<?php
include 'config1.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$searchTerm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid LIKE '%searchTerm%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table height = '30%'border='1'>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='5%'><b>USER ID:</b> {$row['userid']} </td>";
    echo "<td width='5%'><b>USER NAME :</b> {$row['username']} </td>";
    echo "<td width='5%'><b>USER EMAIL:</b> {$row['useremail']} </td>";
    echo "<td width='5%'><b>USER DIVISION:</b> {$row['userdiv']} </td>";
    echo "<td width='5%'><b>USER DEPARTMENT:</b> {$row['userdepartment']} </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
} 
echo"</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Big fan of `&nbsp;`?

Comment: it for spacing. im using dreamweaver. can you help me ? :( . Im newbie

Comment: You should use CSS for spacing, it's much less 90's.

Comment: Well, the code is very messy — so it could be anything causing problems. I would suggest cleaning it up first, then you'll have a better chance at finding the issue perhaps.

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` the detail of `$result`? Also, what is the content of login table?

Comment: var_dump() ? how to use that ? i have 2 php in one page. first php is my session . it for greeting me . welcome me as admin . then the second php is for search user based on user id. im admin and i need to search the user to view their details. login table consists user id username userdiv userdepartment userpass. i combine all in one table. (for login , and registration)

Comment: `var_dump($result)` will output the information about the variable `$result` (value and data type). Your form submit the input to `test.php`, what is the content of that file?

Comment: test.php is a blank page. when i press submit it goes to test.php . it display table.